# Override pseudo class elements bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

```css
nav {
  ol.breadcrumb {
    background-color: unset;

    .breadcrumb-item {
      a {
        color: #0a0a0a;

        &:hover {
          color: #0a0a0a;
          text-decoration: underline;
        }
      }
      &:before {
        &:not(:first-child){
          content: ">>" !important;
        }
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

The above code is of the bootstrap breadcrumbs.In the above SCSS code I've tried to change the **pseudo** element content "/"  to ">>" but the code is not working for me.

If I remove `&:not(:first-child)` section it works. But I don't want ">>" to appear for the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default bootstrap `nav` has more specific styles than yours. There are written like this in `scss`:

```css
nav {
  ol.breadcrumb {
    .breadcrumb-item {
      & + .breadcrumb-item {
        &::before {
          content: ">>" !important;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/txyeg9Ld/6/).

Comment: Additionally how do I position it in the center of the page ? As `text-center` doesn't work well with this.

Comment: Can you please additionally `upvote` and `validate` my answer first ? ;)

Comment: @TanjaForsberg To center it you will have to add `justify-content: center` to `nav ol.breadcrumb`

Comment: @TanjaForsberg Can you please `validate` my answer ?:)